# bootstrap - dynamically changing jumbotron background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the background image of the jumbotron div with jQuery when a new tab is clicked, like this:

```
    $(".about").click(function(){
      $('.active').toggleClass('active');
      $('.about').toggleClass('active');

      $('.jumbotron').fadeOut(500);
      //change background image
      $('.jumbotron').fadeIn(500);
    });
```

I tried using `$('.jumbotron').css('background-image',url('/path/to/new/image'));` but when I include that line, the jumbotron background image doesn't display at all even before I've clicked any of the tabs. Could anyone explain why this is happening please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors otherwise everything is good!! keep `url` inside quotes as below:

```
$('.jumbotron').css('background-image','url(/path/to/new/image)');
```

Comment: Anytime!! Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Hmm - for some reason this has changed the formatting of the h1 element inside the jumbotron also. Have you got any idea why this would happen?

Comment: you might need to add complete code or create a problem fiddle to help on this!!